# How can 4,000 products be easily transfered from one ecommerce solution to another?

Tags: php, import, e-commerce, export, data-transfer

A potential client has a slow ecommerce site using Joomla/Virtuecart which takes 6-10 seconds for any page to load. I've seen faster solutions and would like to transfer the 4,000+ products with little hassle to a speedier, more full-featured open-source solution.

1. Is there a good way to transfer thousands of products between ecommerce programs (CSV file perhaps)?
2. What is a speedy PHP alternative to Virtuecart? Is Cubecart good?

Comment: Too Localized/Not Programming Related. Take your pick.

Comment: This does *not* belong on ServerFault, close voter. SuperUser, maybe.

Comment: If you are developing software, you'd need to write an abstraction layer that can deploy to any of various e-commerce store-fronts. If that doesn't exist already for the sort of stuff you sell, you'll have to develop it.

Answer (score 2):

Re 1.: Depends strongly on the data structure both on the sending and the receiving end. Either way, be prepared for some work and trouble.

As for 2. I can't make a shop system recommendation but I would say, try optimizing what you have first. Joomla is not a pinnacle of code quality and performance - I can't say anything about Virtuecart as I don't know it - but there *must* be some caching solutions around that are definitely worth trying out first. Also, check what other Virtuecart users have done. It might be that much can be achieved doing comparably little tweaking.

And second, it's always the question what is causing the slowness. It could very well be a hosting environment equipped with too few resources, or shared with too many other customers. Before recommending switching to a different solution, I would first e.g. make a local copy of the system and see how it behaves on a normal machine. Maybe even try to install on a different webspace, if it's not too much hassle.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to number 1, schema migrations are a very delicate process and should always be treated with care. Do several test runs before doing anything permanent, live, or destructive. Look for edge cases, funny encodings, etc.

For number 2... I haven't worked with a whole lot, but Zen Cart and Magento come to mind off the top of my head.